# remove recent viewed products in magento won´t work

Tags: magento

Hello I tried to remove the recent viewed product via local.xml, but it did not work and I don´t know why. Here my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
 <reference name="right">
    <action method="unsetChild"><alias>right.reports.product.viewed</alias></action>
    <action method="unsetChild"><alias>right.reports.product.compared</alias></action>
</reference>

<default>
    <action method="unsetChild"><name>right.reports.product.viewed</name></action>
     <action method="unsetChild"><name>right.reports.product.compared</name></action>
    <remove name="right.reports.product.viewed"/>
    <remove name="right.reports.product.compared"/>
</default>
```

Comment: the problem might be `<default>`, because the block is not yet available to use `unsetChild()`. But `<remove>`should work. Did you deactivate the cache?

Comment: Yes. I always work with deactivated caches.

Comment: I had the same issue but the block was on the left so...

<remove name="left.reports.product.viewed"/>