# Remove recently viewed magento content

Tags: php, magento, block

I'm trying to remove "recently viewed" from the home page, but I don't know where the block is called.  I tried to delete `reports.xml` but the block stayed there.  Then I tried to delete all the code in `home_product_viewed.phtml` and it worked, but I don't want to delete the code.  I only want to delete the call to that file but I don't know where that file is called.

Comment: possibly related to [remove recent viewed products in magento won´t work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14143141/remove-recent-viewed-products-in-magento-wont-work)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Goto magento backend.
2. Select the CMS page for homepage.
3. In the *Design* section add the below code in the *Layout Update XML* field

> ```
> <reference name="right">
>     <action method="unsetChild"><alias>right.reports.product.viewed</alias></action>
> </reference>
> ```

Comment: thanks,you helped me a lot, this is not the answer but on the "Desing"  i realize that i had some code to show the product list on main page and i wasnt remembering that i put the code for showing the Viewed products there. so i just delete the block from he home page

Answer (score 2):

To remove it from only the home page, I would do this.  Go to your /app/design/frontend/packagename/themename/layout/local.xml
and edit it like this:

```
<layout>
    <cms_index_index>
       <remove name="right.reports.product.viewed" />
    </cms_index_index>
</layout>
```

To verify your packagname and themename, go in to admin - System - Configuration - Design.
There may already be other code inside of the layout tag which you should leave there!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me -> Using *left* below not right.reports.product.viewed.
Custom Layout Update

```
<reference name="right">
    <action method="unsetChild"><alias>left.reports.product.viewed</alias></action>
</reference>
```